# How to insert a time gap of 1 second between execution of two statements in python

Tags: python, centos

I have a "FOR" loop in the python 2.7 web scraping programme and I am going to insert a time gap of 1 second at the end of the FOR loop. How can I do that?
Thanks.

Comment: `import time; time.sleep(1)`

Comment: Are you looking for [`time.sleep(1)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.sleep) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import the time library: import time;

And use: time.sleep(1)

Comment: Can I use 0.5 sec instead of 1 second? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you could use time.sleep(.5) (notice the dot in front of the 5) :)